# Há algum risco de submeter formulário com HTML?

Tags: html, formulário, segurança

Ao inserir o texto: *`Em 19 de maio de 2015 16:48, <asdfsadf> escreveu:`* e enviar o formulario foi me gerado o seguinte erro:

> A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the
>   client (ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tbObservacao="...o Pedrosa < asdfsadf

O texto foi identificado como *HTML* e perigoso pelo *Asp.Net* o que impediu o formulario de ser submetido, ao que me parece o problema está nesse trecho **`<asdfsadf>`**. Adicionei `ValidateRequest = "false"` a minha página *Aspx* o que desabilita essa validação, mas fiquei com um pé atrás nos efeitos que isso pode causar.

**Minhas dúvidas seriam:**

1. Há algum risco de submeter formulário com *HTML*?
2. Se sim quais?

Comment: Sim, há risco. Basicamente: você vai salvar esse conteúdo no banco e em algum momento vai renderizar uma página para mostrá-lo ao usuário. Como a página estará sendo gerada no contexto do servidor, instruções ASP.NET previamente injetadas e agora recuperadas do banco podem ler dados sensíveis no servidor e enviá-los junto com a página gerada para o usuário malicioso.

Comment: @Caffé não ariscaria uma resposta?

Comment: Gostaria de responder mas no momento não tô podendo - eu estava de passagem :-) Se não aparecer nada, quem sabe mais tarde. Boa sorte aí!

Comment: @Caffé Tranquilo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O ASP.NET, por padrão, valida se existem elementos HTML e outros caracteres especiais nos dados enviados pelo servidor. O motivo disso é a proteção contra vulnerabilidades como Injeções de HTML e Injeções de Script.

Injeções de HTML podem ter muitas consequencias ruins, entre elas o acesso a cookies de usuários, permitindo ao atacante se passar por outro usuário ou a modificação do conteúdo da página visto pelas vítimas.

Um injeção de HTML pode levar a exploração de uma vulnerabilidade mais séria que é o *XSS (Cross Site Scripting)*. Um ataque XSS ocorre quando o atacante consegue utilizar uma aplicação Web para enviar scripts maliciososo para outros usuários. O navegador do usuário não tem como saber que o script não é confiável e por isso ele o executa. Por considerar que o script veio de uma fonte confiável, esse script consegue acessar cookies, chaves de sessão e outras informações sensitivas do usuário que acessa aquele site.

Todas essas injeções podem ser evitadas através da validação do conteúdo enviado na requisição e o ASP.NET já faz isso para você quando a configuração `ValidateRequest` está ligada. Atento para o fato de que essa configuração pode ser feita por página, pelo Web.Config (para aplicação inteira) e até por controle (`ValidateRequestMode="Disabled|Enabled|Inherit"`).

Leia mais a respeito em:

- Sobre HTML Injection e XSS:

  https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTML_Injection

  https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29
- Uma visão voltada para ASP.NET sobre os tipos de injeção:

  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647397.aspx
- Opções de configuração do `ValidateRequest`:

  https://www.owasp.org/index.php/ASP.NET_Request_Validation

Comment: Obrigado pelos links, vou dá uma olhada.

Comment: Estou estudando sobre segurança da informação e decidir voltar aqui, sensacional a resposta, básicamente englobou tudo que estudei.

Comment: Valeu! Espero que ajude mais gente.

Comment: @MarcusVinicius talvez muito depois, mas e se eu tiver um campo apenas que vai vir HTML. Eu tenho que liberar da página inteira mesmo assim? Se eu sei que meu campo pode ter HTML mas só ele, qual é a outra forma de fazer isso, se não com o validaterequest

Comment: @LeandroDeMelloFagundes, não. Desde o .NET 4.5 existe uma propriedade `ValidateRequestMode` que permite essa configuração a nível de controle. Leia mais em https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.control.validaterequestmode?view=netframework-4.7.2